# force git to accept cherry-pick's changes

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I did cherry-pick from a gerrit review in my branch.
In gerrit code review, I have two patch sets and I cherry-picked patch one before, so now I want to do the second patch set, but there are conflicts, how can I force git to accept all changes?
Thanks!

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can tell it to always prefer the changes of the commit you are cherry-picking:

```
git cherry-pick commitish --strategy-option theirs
```

`commitish` can be a SHA-1 hash of a commit, or a `branch-name` for the lastest commit of that branch, `branch-name~1` for the commit before that etc.

If you want to do the reverse, use:

```
git cherry-pick commitish --strategy-option ours
```

The shorthand for `--strategy-option` is `-X` (**upper**cased X).

*PS: [What is the commit-ish, tree-ish?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303550/7512091)*

Comment: if you want to accept incoming changes then you should use `theirs` key otherwise should use  `ours`. u saved my day!

Comment: In my case, this does not force-merge files which have been removed on our branch and modified on theirs. What is the solution to force to accept their changes even if I deleted the files ?

Answer (score 23):

`git cherry-pick -X theirs <commit-hash-you-want-to-force-cherry-pick-from>`

My usual workflow is as follows:

Assuming I'm on the *master* and I have just made a commit.

1. I grab the commit hash of that commit.
2. Then checkout on to the branch I want to have such commit.
3. Then run the command above, e.g. `git cherry-pick -X theirs 5cf3412`

Answer (score 13):

If you are already in conflict state, simply do

```
# add only conflicting files here
git checkout --theirs path/to/file
git add path/to/file
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Answer (score 0):

you could brute force it with something like this:

```
git show cb1e6a:path/to/filename > path/to/filename
git add path/to/filename
git commit
```

but I'm sure there's an easier way.