# Git - Cherry picking with ours/theirs strategy

Tags: git, commit, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, cherry-pick

I wonder if there is any way of cherry picking with ours/theirs strategy. On other words, I want to cherry pick multiple commits from dev branch into main branch with below commands,

```
git cherry-pick HASH1 HASH2 HASH3 -n
```

This command is supposed to take all referred commits and prepare unstaged changes if no conflicts. However, if conflicts, I need to resolve and continue cherry-picking. For all conflicts, my intention is to pick whatever in the dev (which means, `--strategy-option = ours`).

Is there any way to provide such option while cherry-picking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`git cherry-pick` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---strategyltstrategygt) does have the `--strategy`  and `--strategy-option=<option>` options.

They are passed through to the **[merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies)**.

So, in your case:

```
git cherry-pick --strategy=ours HASH1 HASH2 HASH3 -n
```

Comment: I tried, this didn't work for me. It always gives hints to apply after manual conflicts resolution. :(

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan What git version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.11.1, on Mac

Comment: OK, strange. Just for testing, would that be the case with Git 2.14.0?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan it should be working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468531/6309

Comment: I wonder if it gets disabled by `-n` (which uses a somewhat different code path). If so, you could get the same effect by running without `-n`, and then later, squashing.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Did you get torek's comment? Try without the -n

Comment: Its now `git cherry-pick --strategy`

Comment: @koppor Thank you for the feedback, i Have edited the answer accordingly.