# How to rebase a gerrit change using commands?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a gerrit change which has merge conflict with master, when I cherry-pick the change, it says

```
error: could not apply 0819af2... Test change
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
# now git status is as below...
$ git status
## master...origin/master
UU path/to/file
```

I usually open the conflict file in a editor, resolve the conflict and upload the change to gerrit (it gets amended), but how to do the rebase using script so it always picks the change from gerrit being cherry-picked (overwrite whatever is present locally - usually the master), so I can upload the gerrit change without manual intervention? here is what I like to do:

```
git clone a project
apply the gerrit# 1234, if there is conflict, pick the changes from change #1234, overwriting whatever is cloned in current working dir.
Amend the gerrit, so it is rebased now.
```

Comment: I would do a rebase and resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [force a cherry-pick resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468531/6309) with

```
git cherry-pick <sha> --strategy-option theirs
git cherry-pick <sha> -X theirs
```

That way, you can integrate that step in a script which can then run unattended.