Is there a way to duplicate a Git commit with different parents without first replacing?
Consider the following sequence of commands:
git replace --graft <sha> <new_parent_sha>
new_commit_sha="$(git show-ref refs/replace/<sha> | awk '{print $1}')"
git update-ref -d refs/replace/<sha>

The end result is that we have a commit (new_commit_sha) with new parents, that is identical to the original commit (same tree, same message, same author and committer, author date, commit date) except that the parents are different.
Is there a more direct way to achieve the same effect of duplicating a commit with replaced parents without first creating a replace ref and then deleting it?
I looked at git-commit-tree but did not see an option to take most commit properties from a source commit.
I also played with git cherry-pick but that tries to apply a patch which can run into conflicts and results in a different tree if the parent is different. I am trying to produce a commit with exactly the same tree (and other properties).

git restore -s <sha> -S -- . followed by git commit -C <sha> will copy the message+author part. You would still need to use GIT_COMMITTER_* variables if you really need to also copy the committer part from the original commit.

For normal usage, if you want to duplicate a commit, conflicts may occur. This is to prevent the implicit change if a file has changed on both commits.
In case you want the final is your commit and ignore the new parent, it's really not a commit. So there is no way to do this unless touch the ref (like replace), not recommend this way to manage commits.

@AnthonyNguyen I recognize that what I seek is not "normal". I require this to comply with some draconian restrictions imposed by the infra teams at my company.

(after connecting a few more neurons ...) you can also set GIT_COMMITTER_* variables with git cherry-pick. e.g: GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --format=%ce <sha>) ... git cherry-pick <sha>. Do your draconian rules include pgp signatures ?

So in case you want to do this with cherry-pick, try git cherry-pick <commit-sha> --strategy-option theirs. Then edit the meta data of commit as you want.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051850/force-git-to-accept-cherry-picks-changes

Signatures not required. The rule is that we can only deploy artifacts built on the convergence branch. So these hacks will allow me to generate a hot fix PR that brings the main branch to a specific tree, and then replays the previous commits between the hotfix base and the tip of main to preserve git blame history.

@LeGEC Thanks for the comments! I learned about git restore -S, which looks like functionality that does not exist in the git checkout version of the command.

There's an easier way to get the replace ref's sha, and a more direct way to do the whole thing but it's more verbose.
Easier:
git replace --graft $sha $parent1 $parent2 $etc
newcommit=$(git rev-parse refs/replace/$sha)
git replace -d $sha

More direct, but you have to say the exact alterations you want, the idea is Git's commit format is intentionally straightforward plain text, edit it to replace the parents then write the result as a new commit:
newcommit=$(
git cat-file commit $sha | sed -f $youredits | git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin
)

so for instance the above with two parents and without bothering with the replace-ref tango on a GNU system is
newcommit=$(
exec {sedpgm}<<EOD
1,/^ *$/ { /^parent/d; }   # delete existing parents in the header; add new ones:
1aparent $parent1
1aparent $parent2
EOD
git cat-file commit $sha | sed -f /dev/fd/$sedpgm | git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin
#exec {sedpgm}<&- # not needed in a subshell that's going to exit anyway
)

If you don't have a GNU sed or shell you get to construct the edit instructions to suit your own toolset; it's easier, likely even a bit cheaper, and probably clearer to just do the git replace, it's got the parent-rewiring dance down cold.

p.s. on a side tangent using more shell readability features, maybe this is getting too deep in the weeds here but if you do have the tools you can get good use of the shell's line-at-a-time readin to make it clearer. (This unfortunately horribly confuses SO's builtin syntax coloring, and even emacs's, but unsurprisingly not vim's.) Markdown eats tabs but the shell can use them to make inline data easier on the eyes, here's what I really used for my smoketest on a two-parent merge here, all leading whitespace is tabs:
sha=$(git rev-parse @)
newcommit=$(
git cat-file commit $sha | sed -f /dev/fd/3 3<<-EOD| git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin
    1,/^ *$/ { /^parent/d; }   # delete existing parents in the header; add new ones:
    1aparent $(git rev-parse @^1)
    1aparent $(git rev-parse @^2)
    EOD
)

or even
sha=$(git rev-parse @)
newcommit=$(
git cat-file commit $sha | sed -f /dev/fd/3 3<<-EOD \
| git hash-object -w -t commit --stdin
    1,/^ *$/ { /^parent/d; }   # delete existing parents in the header; add new ones:
    1aparent $(git rev-parse @^1)
    1aparent $(git rev-parse @^2)
    EOD
)


This got me pretty close to replicating the git replace functionality with lower level commands.
For others' reference, the only missing bit to exactly replicate the commit produced by git replace was that I had to modify the sed command to strip out the (no longer valid) gpg signatures.

Also, I agree with the advice that using git replace is easier in this case, but seeing this answer and trying to replicate the functionality manually was very educational for me. :)

Thanks, I added some more shell-readability tricks in case they're up your alley too
